# Reading from textfile into a list and then writing back to that list Python/CGI

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am trying to basically get the data from keywords.txt and put it into a list.  Then, if the user entered data in the form is not in the list, it gets written to the file and it will take the user to a certain webpage depending on if it is in the list or not.  I essentially want the file to be just full of words with one word on a line but first I am just trying to get it to work.

I am having trouble understand what variable the user entered data is if that makes any sense.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
keyword = form.getvalue('keyword')


print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r'
print '<html>'
print '<h1>Please enter a keyword of your choice</h1>'
print '<form action="results.cgi" method="post">'
print 'Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword">  <br />'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />'
print '</form>'
print '</html>'

keylist = []
f = open('keywords.txt', 'rw')
for each in f.readline():
    keylist.append(each)

if keyword in keylist:
    print 'Location: %s' % # my url

else:
    f.write(keyword)
    f.close()
    print 'Location: %s' % # my second url
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in f.readline()
```

only uses the first line, the result of f.readline. So, the variable each will be each character of the first line.

If you use

```
for each in f.read().split()
```

you should get what you want. f.read() reads the whole file at once, and split() splits at the newlines (and at all types of white spaces)

In addition to that, you should use rw+ mode to open the file, else you would get an IOError.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However I am still wondering how to tell what is the variable for the user input so I can add that to my file.  If you see right now I have "if keyword in keylist" and "f.write(keyword)" but that is not correct

Comment: Maybe try: `keyword = form['keyword'].value`

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your question, but reading your code, I saw, that **you only close** the file, **if the keyword** is **not** in your *keylist*.

Maybe you want to move

> f.close()

below the else-condition. Just an idea, though.

And yes, I would go with the answer from *Hyperboreus*:

> for line in f.readlines(): *#where line could just as easily be your 'each'*